# How to write a unit test to verify that one python instance method calls several other instance methods in the correct order?

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def _RunPhase1(self):
        for d in data:
            d = d * 3

    def _RunPhase1(self):
        for d in data:
            d = (d / 2) + 5.0

    def RunProcessingSequence(self):
        self._RunPhase1()
        self._RunPhase2()
```

Pardon the contrived nature of this sample code. I'd like to know how to compose a unit test for instance method RunProcessingSequence that would verify that it does in fact call the "private" instance methods _RunPhase1 and _RunPhase2 in that order.

I've tried this approach but it doesn't seem to work:

```
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('__main__.Example')
    def test_RunProcessingSequence(self, mock_e):
        e = Example([1, 2, 3])
        mock_e.return_value = e
        e.RunProcessingSequence()
        expected = [e._RunPhase1, e._RunPhase2]
        self.assertTrue(mock_e.call_args_list == expected)
```

How might I change my code under test, or my test method, to achieve the desired result?

Comment: it is far far far better that the unit test has zero knowledge of any of that.   It should run `RunProcessingSequence` and expect an observable result.  Unit tests are super fragile if they start knowing the internal implementation of things.

Comment: I have a stronger foundation in C# unit tests, and I read Osherove's _The Art of Unit Testing_, and he distinguishes between state-based tests (that scrutinize method return values) and interaction tests that verify that CUT make the appropriate side-effect calls (as it were). I'm trying to find out how to accomplish the latter in Python when I have one instance method that calls other instance methods. Maybe I just need to consider another OO pattern that would allow me to write the test that I have in mind in a straight-forward way with while minimizing brittleness...?